# Date does not appear in UILabel

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

What is wrong with this code?

```
    NSString *strTest = @"Sun Apr 12 23:29:24 +0000 2009";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yy"];
    NSDate *createdAtFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strTest];
    self.createdAt.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:createdAtFormatted];
```

self.createdAt is a UILabel and it stays empty. Why?

When trying to use dateWithNaturalLanguageString, I get:

[image]

Comment: Because the formatter fails to convert the string to a date. `createdAtFormatted` is `nil`. You have to match the format string with the date string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your date formatter date format does not match the date format from the `strTest` string.

```
NSString *strTest = @"Sun Apr 12 23:29:24 +0000 2009";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *loc = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]; // so the formatter recognizes english names for months and days
[dateFormatter setLocale:loc];
[loc release]; // remove if using ARC
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM d HH:mm:ss ZZZZ yyyy"];
NSDate *createdAtFormatted = [dateFormatter dateFromString:strTest];
NSLog(@"got %@", createdAtFormatted);
```

The formatter specifiers can be found [here](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: Could you help me with the string format? I don't know how to create it correctly for my string.

Comment: Sure - I'd go for `NSDate *createdAtFormatted = [NSDate dateWithNaturalLanguageString:strTest];`. I tried setting formatter flags, but the month part kept failing (Apr). This solution is quick and works, but the use of the function is not encouraged, since it can produce unexpected results if it fails to read the format.

Comment: It says dateWithNaturalLanguageString is not known class method. I am using Xcode 4.2 and Snow Leopard.

Comment: That's odd, can you paste the complete error log in a screenshot?

Comment: Got it, my bad (`dateWithNaturalLanguageString:` is from the Mac OS SDK, not iOS). I edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

You are giving MM/dd/yy pattern to dateFormatter but your date string is not fit for that thus dateFormatter returning a nil date.